# how to pass the most recent file from a directory to awk input file?

Tags: file, input, awk

It should be something like that :

```
    awk '

       ...

     ' ls -rt | tail -n 1
```

"ls -rt | tail -n 1" is the name of the most recent file from a directory

Thank you in advance

Comment: IMHO experts never advice to parse `ls` output to `awk` command.

Comment: I'm very beginner. I don't know how to make a variable for the awk's input file

Comment: this won't be robust for all filenames, but may work for you: `ls -rt | tail -n1 | xargs -d'\n' awk '<code>'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use format mentioned below, please choose separtor and required field to print as per your 'ls -lr' output.

```
 ls -lr <directoryName|*>| tail -n 1|awk -F<separator> '{ print $<tokenNumber> }'
```

Example:

```
ls -lr cpas| tail -n 1|awk -F: '{ print $2 }'
```

[image]