# Process the latest version of a file ..... as the 2nd file of a pair of files that are to be processed

Tags: awk, recent-file-list

Using gawk I want to process two files in a directory.
The first file has a fixed name but whilst the start of the name of the second file is constant the name ends in a date and time stamp, the latter changes everytime the file is created.
I want to use the latest version of the second file.

I have seen a post/answer to a similar but less complicated question at
[how to pass the most recent file from a directory to awk input file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61222002/how-to-pass-the-most-recent-file-from-a-directory-to-awk-input-file)
and the code `ls -lr 2nd_file_*| tail -n 1` does show me the latest file.
However I do not know how to pass the found file name to gawk as the second file.

Currently I type the date/time stamp into the gawk script e.g.

```
gawk -F[,"\t""}"] '{ do something }' file_1 2nd_file_2024_03_21_[18-21-32] > output_file
```

Does anyone know how I can do this ?
Thanks.

I haven't tried anything as I haven't a clue how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting aside the various issues with [parsing 'ls' output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) one simple approach would see the 2nd file/argument (to the `awk` script) replaced with a subshell invocation of the `ls|tail` call, eg:

```
awk '{ do something }' file_1 $( ls -1r 2nd_file_* | tail -n 1 )
```

**NOTE:** OP has stated this particular `ls|tail` combo provides the desired file name so I'm merely copying it here as an example.

---

To see this in action we'll start with some sample files:

```
$ head *
==> 2nd_file_2024_03_21 <==
21

==> 2nd_file_2024_03_22 <==
22

==> 2nd_file_2024_03_23 <==
23

==> 2nd_file_2024_03_24 <==
24

==> file_1 <==
line_1
```

To obtain the latest `2nd_file_*` we need a tweak to OP's current `ls|tail`:

```
$ ls -1 2nd_file_* | tail -n 1
2nd_file_2024_03_24
```

Wrapping this in subshell invocation and feeding to a simple `awk` script that prints each input line to stdout:

```
$ awk '{ print }' file_1 $( ls -1 2nd_file_* | tail -n 1 )
line_1                                                       # line from file_1
24                                                           # line from 2nd_file_2024_03_24
```

Comment: Blimey that was quick, thanks Mark. It works too, with a minor modification, I had to drop the -lr bit and do a simple ls.

Comment: I do not know what is causing the "ouch" but I timed out on editing the above comment  so .......I am not sure I understand the reason for discussing or showing the "head" stuff but it seems to me that the $(xys) is 'saying' "use the 'value' created by the stuff inside the ( )". I have used that same mechanism elsewhere, in the program that created file-2. Anyway, thank you very much..

Comment: `head *` says (for each file in the current directory) to display the filename (`==> filename <==`) followed by the first 10 lines of said file; this allows me to show the contents of my directory and the contents of each file; these sample inputs are then used to demonstrate the follow-on `ls|tail` and `awk` commands; net result: I've provided a [minimal, reproducible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which anyone should be able to reproduce in their system (in an initially empty directory)

Answer (score 1):

Shell (Bash at least) processes files in lexicographic (or alphabetical) order and as your dates in filenames seem to have leading zeroes (hoping the time parts to have as well) `2nd_file*` will give the last file last.

First some test data:

```
$ for i in file_1 2nd_file_2 2nd_file_1  # test stuff, notice order
> do
>   echo $i > $i                         # one line of content in each file
>   sleep 2                              # some time difference
> done
$ ls -lrt
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  7 Mar 28 10:00 file_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 11 Mar 28 10:00 2nd_file_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 11 Mar 28 10:00 2nd_file_1
```

And some GNU awk:

```
$ gawk '
{
    if(ARGIND==1 || !((ARGIND+1) in ARGV))  # process 1st and last file
        print FILENAME                      # do something
    else
        nextfile                            # jump to nextfile
}' file_1 2nd_file_*
```

Output:

```
file_1
2nd_file_2
```

From [the GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#index-ARGIND-variable): ***ARGIND** The index in `ARGV` of the current file being processed. Every time gawk opens a new data file for processing, it sets `ARGIND` to the index in `ARGV` of the file name. When gawk is processing the input files, `'FILENAME == ARGV[ARGIND]'` is always true.*

Of course if the files had more than one record in them, above would print more than one line of `FILENAME` for each file (which you fix by removing the `else`), so eventually you want to:

```
$ gawk '
!(ARGIND==1 || !((ARGIND+1) in ARGV)) {  # if not first or last file
    nextfile                             # skip it
}
{
    ;                                    # do stuff   
}' file_1 2nd_file_*
```

Comment: Thanks James. That will take me sometime to get to grips with.